# How to install Mono on a server?

Tags: software-installation, mono

I'd like to be able to build and run C# programs on my Ubuntu 10.10 server. How do I install Mono? "sudo apt-get install mono" doesn't work, says "Package mono is not available, but is referred to by another package".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this

`sudo apt-get install mono-complete`

Comment: What version does this install? Latest stable?

Comment: Does the "mono-complete" installs X11 with it !? Imo, I don't think this is the best choice on a server...

Answer (score 8):

The mono compiler package is `mono-gmcs`, if you need the entire mono stack, install the package `mono-complete` .

Comment: What's the difference between the complete mono stack and the compiler package?

Answer (score 8):

You can install only mono runtime. Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-runtime
```

Comment: This might not be enough, though. My installation was missing necessary .dlls with this. For more information, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490155/unable-to-run-net-app-with-mono-mscorlib-dll-not-found-version-mismatch